# py и pyw кнопка "Изменить" в контестном меню

Tags: python, windows

Не подскажете, каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы, нажав на правую клавишу мыши по файлу питона, появлялась кнопка "Изменить", нажав на которую файл откроется в блокноте?
(использую windows 10 и Notepad2, который сидит в ProgramFilesx86)

Пока добился того, что могу создать именно кнопку, но windows пишет:
"Не удается получить доступ к указанному устройству, пути или файлу. Возможно у вас нет нужных разрешений для доступа к этому объекту."

Код reg файла:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\opennp]
@="Изменить"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\opennp\command]
@="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Notepad2\\Notepad2.exe %1"
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не распознает переменные среды %SystemRoot%

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\edit]
@="Изменить"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\edit\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad2\\Notepad2.exe\" \"%L\"
```

Так же срабатывает так:

```
@="\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\NOTEPAD.EXE\"  \"%L\""
```

Comment: @insolor, для информации....

Comment: Что для информации? Я вам ничего не писал по поводу этих двух вопросов-ответов. Кстати, обращения работают только внутри вопроса, где участник как-то отметился (написал ответ или комментарий). Тут не понятно вообще что вы хотели мне сказать этим.

Comment: @insolor, хорошо, учту,     мы с Вами обсуждали тему IDLE и Notepad2, я отметил для информации, вдруг еще кто спросит, или Вам пригодится...

Comment: Мне не пригодится - я не пользуюсь ни IDLE (к счастью), ни Windows)